# Upload form and input:file selector not working?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I making an upload form for *.pdf

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="file_sm">Upload File:</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
         <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
           Browse <input type="file" name="file_sm[]" id="file_sm" name="file_sm" accept="application/pdf"/>
         </span>
       </span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and using JQuery for $_POST the data to `sm.input.php`

```js
$("#save-sm").bind("click", function(event) {
  var url = "sm.input.php";

  var v_file_sm = $('input:file[name=file_sm]').val();

  // sending for process
  $.post(url, {file_sm: v_file_sm, id: id_sm} ,function() {

    // show data <div id="data-sm"></div>
    $("#data-sm").load(main);

    // hide modal dialog
    $('#dialog-sm').modal('hide');

  });
});
```

and inside `sm.input.php` file:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_sm'])){
 foreach($_FILES['file_sm']['name'] as $key => $val){
  $name = $_FILES['file_sm']['name'][$key];
  $tmp  = $_FILES['file_sm']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $file_size    = $_FILES['file_sm']['size'][$key];

  if($file_size < 50000){       
      if(trim($name)!=''){
          $new_name = date('YmdHis').'_'.$name; //rename file

          if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,'/upload/'.$new_name)){ 
              $file_sm = $new_name;
          }
      }
  } else {
      echo "MAX 50KB";
  }
 }
}
```

why input:file selector JQuery is not working for me?
the file didn't uploading and the php server can't get the file name.. whats wrong with my code?

---

I read about AJAX file uploading, but I still cant understand how to implement on my code :(

Comment: You cannot simply retrieve the `val` of a file input. See the top answer in the question I marked as duplicate for an explanation of the problem and the working code.

Comment: it hs couple of name attributes...remove the one with "[]" it should work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you tell me more detail? Im newbie :(